# How do I resolve thingsboard edge UI problem?

Tags: java, http, interface, cloud, thingsboard

I am not able to install Thingsboard Edge. In the localhost UI Page, "invalid credentials" message is being shown upon entering the same. How to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Did you take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? How did you install Thingsboard Edge and how did you start it locally?

Comment: I have installed it by following the steps in installation [guide](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/edge/windows/?edgeInstallCloud=pe)  available online. Since it was installed locally, I used this link to get access to the website : http://localhost:8080/login

Comment: Do you use the profession or community edition? Did you install thingsboard to your windows machine or run it inside of Docker? What happens when you try to open localhost:8080/login or try to login on the page? Do you have any logs of the thingsboard service? Please seriously go through the link on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you expect people to help you.

Comment: Please edit your question and add this information. Furthermore, please provide the configuration of TB on EC2 and on your windows machine, as well as any logs of either TB instance you have.